# Calculo de Tabuada em Java,usando laços de Repetição

Tags: java, loop

Não estou conseguindo resolver o seguinte exercício:

> Apresentar os resultados da tabuada de um número qualquer. O usuário informa qual valor deseja. A tabuada deve ser realizada desde 0 até 10, utilizando a técnica do laço de repetição com teste lógico no fim do looping.

Eu só posso usar : DO e  WHILE..

Por enquanto meu código no ECLIPSE está assim:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tabuada {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         int A;

        Scanner tab = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Informar um número");
        A = tab.nextInt();

    }

}
```

Comment: Você consegue escrever o código com algum tipo de laço, por exemplo com for? Porque no seu código não tem nada relativo à tentativa de solução ainda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você só precisa de uma variável para representar o multiplicador do valor de entrada e controlar o valor desta variável dentro do *loop*.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        int entrada;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Informar um número: ");
        entrada = scanner.nextInt();

        int multiplicador = 0;
        while(multiplicador <= 10)
        {
            int resultado = entrada * multiplicador;
            System.out.println(resultado);   
            multiplicador++;
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no repl.it**](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/VerifiableBustlingMacroinstruction)</sup>

Comment: Ela só pode usar do-while. Além disso, simplesmente implementar para a pessoa não é exatamente o propósito do site.

Comment: @prmottajr A lógica continua exatamente a mesma. Eu não tô aqui pra fazer trabalho de terceiros. Btw, eu expliquei exatamente como funciona o código, é simples, não tem o que ficar enrolando. Eu conheço muito bem o propósito do site.

Comment: São coisas separadas. Eu comentei na pergunta pedindo que fosse informado o que já havia sido tentado. Da forma como a pergunta foi feita ficou "façam para mim". Apenas comentei sobre não ser o propósito porque já havia sinalizado na própria pergunta que a colaboração não era exatamente assim. E não era meu objetivo ofender.

Comment: @prmottajr Sim, eu sei. O que eu quis dizer a você é que não tem muito como tentar explicar sem fazer o código. De qualquer forma, eu vou tentar editar e explicar melhor.

Answer (score 2):

Outro exemplo, com um laço externo para poder repetir a operação da tabuada com outros valores de entrada.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int A;
    do {
        Scanner tab = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Informar um número (0(zero) para finalizar):");

        A = tab.nextInt();
        if (A != 0) {
            int mult = 0;
            while (mult < 10) {
                mult++;
                System.out.println(A + " * " + mult + "  = " + (A * mult));
            }
        }
    } while (A != 0);

}
```

Comment: O enunciado não fala nada de ficar em loop lendo outras entradas. Para a lógica principal, você usou while e não do-while. E a proposta do site é ajudar em implementações, não dar elas prontas quando a pessoa não mostrou alguma coisa concreta.

Comment: @prmottajr o exemplo mostra as duas formas de utilizar o while. Não espero que o autor simplismente pegue meu código, mas se o fizer, não vejo problema. Com suas palavras "_a proposta do site é ajudar em implementações_"

Comment: Eu comentei na pergunta pedindo que fosse informado o que já havia sido tentado. Da forma como a pergunta foi feita ficou "façam para mim". Por isso comentei aqui, o problema não está nas respostas em si, mas na forma como a pergunta foi colocada. No final, as respostas acabam incentivando a busca por soluções de exercícios sem que a pessoa apresente o que tentou fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Também pode ser feito da forma abaixo:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int valorUsuario;
    int multiplicador = 0;
    int total = 0;


    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Informe um número: ");
    valorUsuario = ler.nextInt();

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            total = valorUsuario * ++multiplicador;
            System.out.println(valorUsuario + " x " + multiplicador + " = " + total);
        }

    }
```